# Add a custom WooCommerce settings page, including page sections

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, settings

I'm trying to add a custom settings tab to the WooCommerce settings screen. Basically I want to achieve a similar thing to the Products settings tab, with the subsections/subtabs:

[image: WooCommerce Products settings tab]

I haven't been able to find any decent documentation on how to do this but I've been able to add a custom tab using this snippet:

```php
class WC_Settings_Tab_Demo {

    public static function init() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', __CLASS__ . '::add_settings_tab', 50 );
    }

    public static function add_settings_tab( $settings_tabs ) {
        $settings_tabs['test'] = __( 'Settings Demo Tab', 'woocommerce-settings-tab-demo' );
        return $settings_tabs;
    }
}
WC_Settings_Tab_Demo::init();
```

[image: Custom WooCommerce settings tab]

Based on what I've dug up from various threads/tutorials, I've been trying to add the sections/subtabs to the new settings tab something like this:

```php
// creating a new sub tab in API settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sections_test','add_subtab' );
function add_subtab( $sections ) {
    $sections['custom_settings'] = __( 'Custom Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
    $sections['more_settings'] = __( 'More Settings', 'woocommerce-custom-settings-tab' );
    return $sections;
}


// adding settings (HTML Form)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_settings_test', 'add_subtab_settings', 10, 2 );
function add_subtab_settings( $settings, $current_section ) {
    // $current_section = (isset($_GET['section']) && !empty($_GET['section']))? $_GET['section']:'';
    if ( $current_section == 'custom_settings' ) {
        $custom_settings = array();
        $custom_settings[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Custom Settings', 'text-domain' ),
                                   'type' => 'title',
                                   'desc' => __( 'The following options are used to ...', 'text-domain' ),
                                   'id' => 'custom_settings'
                                  );

        $custom_settings[] = array(
                                    'name'     => __( 'Field 1', 'text-domain' ),
                                    'id'       => 'field_one',
                                    'type'     => 'text',
                                    'default'  => get_option('field_one'),

                                );

        $custom_settings[] = array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'test-options' );
        return $custom_settings;
    } else {
        // If not, return the standard settings
        return $settings;
    }
}
```

I've been able to add new subsections to the Products tab using similar code to the above, but it isn't working for my new custom tab. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)** To add a setting tab with sections, you can firstly use the `woocommerce_settings_tabs_array` filter hook:

```php
// Add the tab to the tabs array
function filter_woocommerce_settings_tabs_array( $settings_tabs ) {
    $settings_tabs['my-custom-tab'] = __( 'My custom tab', 'woocommerce' );

    return $settings_tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 'filter_woocommerce_settings_tabs_array', 99 );
```

**2)** To add new sections to the page, you can use the `woocommerce_sections_{$current_tab}` composite hook where `{$current_tab}` need to be replaced by the key slug that is set in the first function:

```php
// Add new sections to the page
function action_woocommerce_sections_my_custom_tab() {
    global $current_section;

    $tab_id = 'my-custom-tab';

    // Must contain more than one section to display the links
    // Make first element's key empty ('')
    $sections = array(
        ''              => __( 'Overview', 'woocommerce' ),
        'my-section-1'  => __( 'My section 1', 'woocommerce' ),
        'my-section-2'  => __( 'My section 2', 'woocommerce' )
    );

    echo '<ul class="subsubsub">';

    $array_keys = array_keys( $sections );

    foreach ( $sections as $id => $label ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=' . $tab_id . '&section=' . sanitize_title( $id ) ) . '" class="' . ( $current_section == $id ? 'current' : '' ) . '">' . $label . '</a> ' . ( end( $array_keys ) == $id ? '' : '|' ) . ' </li>';
    }

    echo '</ul><br class="clear" />';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_sections_my-custom-tab', 'action_woocommerce_sections_my_custom_tab', 10 );
```

---

**3)** For adding the settings, as well as for processing/saving, we will use a custom function, which we will then call:

```php
// Settings function
function get_custom_settings() {
    global $current_section;

    $settings = array();

    if ( $current_section == 'my-section-1' ) {

        // My section 1
        $settings = array(

            // Title
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Your title 1', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'      => 'title',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_1'
            ),

            // Text
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Your title 1.1', 'text-domain' ),
                'type'      => 'text',
                'desc'      => __( 'Your description 1.1', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'  => true,
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_1_text',
                'css'       => 'min-width:300px;'
            ),

            // Select
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Your title 1.2', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc'      => __( 'Your description 1.2', 'woocommerce' ),
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_1_select',
                'class'     => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                'css'       => 'min-width:300px;',
                'default'   => 'aa',
                'type'      => 'select',
                'options'   => array(
                    'aa'        => __( 'aa', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'bb'        => __( 'bb', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'cc'        => __( 'cc', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'dd'        => __( 'dd', 'woocommerce' ),
                ),
                'desc_tip' => true,
            ),

            // Section end
            array(
                'type'      => 'sectionend',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_1'
            ),
        );
    
    } elseif ( $current_section == 'my-section-2' ) {

        // My section 2
        $settings = array(

            // Title
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Your title 2', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'      => 'title',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_2'
            ),

            // Text
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Your title 2.2', 'text-domain' ),
                'type'      => 'text',
                'desc'      => __( 'Your description 2.1', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'  => true,
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_2_text',
                'css'       => 'min-width:300px;'
            ),

            // Section end
            array(
                'type'      => 'sectionend',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_2'
            ),
        );
    
    } else {
        // Overview
        $settings = array(

            // Title
            array(
                'title'     => __( 'Overview', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'      => 'title',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_overview'
            ),

            // Section end
            array(
                'type'      => 'sectionend',
                'id'        => 'custom_settings_overview'
            ),
        );
    }

    return $settings;
}
```

**3.1)** Add settings, via the `woocommerce_settings_{$current_tab}` composite hook:

```php
// Add settings
function action_woocommerce_settings_my_custom_tab() {
    // Call settings function
    $settings = get_custom_settings();

    WC_Admin_Settings::output_fields( $settings );  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_my-custom-tab', 'action_woocommerce_settings_my_custom_tab', 10 );
```

**3.2)** Process/save the settings, via the `woocommerce_settings_save_{$current_tab}` composite hook:

```php
// Process/save the settings
function action_woocommerce_settings_save_my_custom_tab() {
    global $current_section;

    $tab_id = 'my-custom-tab';

    // Call settings function
    $settings = get_custom_settings();

    WC_Admin_Settings::save_fields( $settings );

    if ( $current_section ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_' . $tab_id . '_' . $current_section );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_save_my-custom-tab', 'action_woocommerce_settings_save_my_custom_tab', 10 );
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

Based on:

- [Implement a custom WooCommerce settings page, including page sections](https://gist.github.com/renventura/ff93a87f8779457b72ff4dc0366ba053)
- [woocommerce/includes/admin/settings/](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/settings)